# Show xtick labels on upper subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, plot, visualization

I feel like I've tried everything I've been able to find here, google, matplotlib documentation, and a couple of other forums. I can't get xticks to show on the upper subplot/graph, and the lower. I read in a forum related to matplotlib that others had the same problem as I, with earlier versions of matplotlib, but the thread died a couple of years ago, and the fixes that was suggested to work, didn't in my case.

The data is pulled from CSV files, and converted to floats, and datetime values

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

y = [26.0, 24.6, 23.9, 23.7, 23.6, 21.8, 22.0, 23.6]
x = [datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 13), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 23), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 33), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 43), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 53), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 3, 0, 3), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 4, 0, 3), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 4, 0, 13)]
out = {datetime.date(2020, 9, 2): [26.0, 24.6, 23.9, 23.7, 23.6], datetime.date(2020, 9, 3): [21.8], datetime.date(2020, 9, 4): [21.6, 21.6]}

'''I found a thread a couple of days ago, where these 2 lines were the fix. honestly don't remember what the problem was, except it was related to datetime and plt'''
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())

ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('temp')
plt.title('logs')
plt.grid()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'))

'''and also found how to subplot a boxplot from dict, from another thread'''
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
labels, data = [*zip(*out.items())]  # 'transpose' items to parallel key, value lists
plt.boxplot(data)
plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels) + 1), labels)
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('temp')

'''for rotating the xticklabels, and as far as I've been able to read, the most likely culprit'''
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.draw() # non-blocking call

plt.show() # keep last in script to keep windows open after execution
```

[image: This is the result]

It might just be `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()` and if it is, is there a way to show xticklabels for both subplots, and still have them rotated?

Comment: One problem is that `plt.gca().xaxis.set_...` needs to be called after creating the subptlot (`plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)` creates the first subplot). And then again after creating the second subplot.   This type of changes are more straightforward using [matplotlib's object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

Comment: wouldn't it be nicer to have only the lower x axis labeled but aligned with the one from the upper plot?

Comment: @MrFuppes it's not a problem that they're slightly misaligned. Since the upper plot uses datetime, it would be nice, also for when you zoom, that you are able to see both the date and time for the recordings, where the lower boxplot, shows the data for each date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by JohanC, you should use the [matplotlib's object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

You can create the two subplots you need and then customize the axis based on your needs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as datetime
import matplotlib.dates as md


y = [26.0, 24.6, 23.9, 23.7, 23.6, 21.8, 22.0, 23.6]
x = [datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 13), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 23), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 33), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 43), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 53), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 3, 0, 3), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 4, 0, 3), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 4, 0, 13)]
out = {datetime.date(2020, 9, 2): [26.0, 24.6, 23.9, 23.7, 23.6], datetime.date(2020, 9, 3): [21.8], datetime.date(2020, 9, 4): [21.6, 21.6]}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

ax[0].plot(x, y)
ax[0].set_xlabel('time')
ax[0].set_ylabel('temp')
ax[0].set_title('logs')
ax[0].grid()

labels, data = [*zip(*out.items())]
ax[1].boxplot(data)
ax[1].set_xticklabels([label.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for label in labels])
ax[1].set_xlabel('date')
ax[1].set_ylabel('temp')

ax[0].xaxis.tick_top()
ax[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(md.DayLocator())
plt.setp(ax[0].xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 45)
ax[0].set_xlim(labels[0], labels[-1])

plt.setp(ax[1].xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 45)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Side note: lower and upper labels are not perfectly aligned because you are trying to compare two different types of axis: to top upper one is continuous (between one tick and the next there are many other possible values for hours, minutes, seconds)
while the lower one is categorical (you are plotting values for days only and between one thick and the next there are no others).

Comment: This helped me get the xtick labels for the top axis. The boxplot is useful for getting a quick overview of a lot of data, sorted into smaller portions, where the graph are supposed to give a more complete dataset, so it is on purpose, that the boxplot used date, while the graph used datetime

Comment: regarding the side note, intuitively I'd prefer subplots with `sharex=True`, but that requires to use matplotlib.dates for the x-axis (numeric time axis) to then access the `positions` of the box plots. But it depends on what the plot is intended for, and taste I guess ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using Matplotilb's object-oriented interface that let's you align the axes and rotate the labels on them. Sharing the xaxis in subplots makes it so that the zoom works for both subplots.

The ticks on the upper subplot are turned on by using

```
up.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
```

The boxplots are positioned using matplotlib's date-value corresponding to the datetimes using

```
mdates.date2num(d)
```

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import datetime


y = [26.0, 24.6, 23.9, 23.7, 23.6, 21.8, 22.0, 23.6]
x = [datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 13), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 23), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 33), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 43), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 2, 14, 53), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 3, 0, 3), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 4, 0, 3), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 4, 0, 13)]
out = {datetime.date(2020, 9, 2): [26.0, 24.6, 23.9, 23.7, 23.6], datetime.date(2020, 9, 3): [21.8], datetime.date(2020, 9, 4): [21.6, 21.6]}


f, (up, down) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

up.plot(x, y)
up.set_xlabel('time')
up.set_ylabel('temp')
up.set_title('logs')
up.grid()

down.boxplot(
    out.values(),
    positions=[mdates.date2num(d) for d in out.keys()]
)

down.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'))
down.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())

up.tick_params(labelbottom=True)

plt.setp( up.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=30 )
plt.setp( down.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=30 )

f.tight_layout()
plt.draw()
```

Note that [autofmt_xdate](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) explicitly turns off the ticklabels for all subplots except the bottom one(s?).

> Date ticklabels often overlap, so it is useful to rotate them and right align them. Also, a common use case is a number of subplots with shared x-axis where the x-axis is date data. The ticklabels are often long, and it helps to rotate them on the bottom subplot and **turn them off on other subplots, as well as turn off xlabels**.

This answer is similar to @Zephyr's answer, but I'm posting it anyway as it properly aligns the data between the plots. You could change the alignment by setting a different time of the day on the lower plot or by changing the boxes' width.

[image: The result]